# How to sort varchar week of the month column in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, calendar

I have calendar table where last column is `varchar` "`WeekOfMonth`". What would be the most efficient way to create column `WeekOfMonthSort`?

[image]

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = CAST(DATEADD(yy, -2, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS DATE),
        @MaxDate DATE = CAST(GETDATE() + 90 as DATE);

;WITH cte_Calendar AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
    FROM    
        sys.all_objects a
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.all_objects b
) 
SELECT 
    Date,
    MONTH(Date) AS MonthNum,
    YEAR(Date) AS YearNum,
    FORMAT(Date, 'MMM') AS Month,
    FORMAT(Date, 'MMM') + '-'+ FORMAT(Date, 'yy') AS  'MM-YY',
    YEAR(Date) * 12 + MONTH(Date) -1 AS 'MM-YY Sort',
    --'Week-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATEPART(wk, Date)) AS Week,
    YEAR(Date) + DATEPART(wk, Date) AS 'Week Sort',
    WeekOfMonth = 'Week-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), CONVERT(TINYINT, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) ORDER BY DATEPART(wk, Date))))
FROM
    cte_Calendar
```

[image]

I tried to combine Year and week number but when new year starts Sort value for previous year becomes less than next year.

[image]

Comment: Considering that there won't be more than 4 weeks in a month, the sort order of `WeekOfMonth` won't differ it the value is a `varchar` with the format `Week-#` or just a single digit with the week number and the value was an `int` (which ideally you should be storing the value as). What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I just need to come up with integer number to spread out weeks by several years.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The order returned is the same, regardless of the data type of `WeekOfMonth`; not unless you end up with `'Week-10` and no month has 10 weeks. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=01365a908a5c243f1e89e9dee4c7f01f)

Comment: Sorry, if I am confusing you. I attached a snip, where date parameter is for 2019 year. So I need to stretch out chart for each month and week, and also for each year, month and week

Comment: I think it's time for sample data (not an image) and expected results. I still have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: How about DATEPART(wk, Date) combined with year?

Comment: What does "stretch out chart" even mean?   How does it have anything to do with Ordering?

Comment: @Gigga I tried to combine Year and Week but when next year starts, sort value for previous year becomes becomes larger than value for next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to answer this ....

```
YEAR(Date) + DATEPART(wk, Date) AS 'Week Sort',
```

The above statement does not make sense. I suspect you are mixing up string concatenation with number addition, i.e.
`YEAR(Date) + DATEPART(wk, Date)` gives you 2019 + 10 = 2029 which is not what you expect but then I also notice that

```
YEAR(Date) * 12 + MONTH(Date) -1 AS 'MM-YY Sort'
```

is coded correctly.

To combine year and month numbers together you need to do an equivalent of string append or in other words similar to what is done for 'MM-YY Sort'.

Arithmetically (because output of `YEAR` and `DATEPART(wk` functions is numeric) what you need to do is:

```
YEAR(Date) * 100 + DATEPART(wk, Date) AS 'Week Sort'
```

The result for week 10 will be 2019 * 100 + 10 = 201900 + 10 = 201910 and 201911 for week 11.

You can also achieve the same result using string concatenation:

```
CAST( YEAR(Date) AS VARCHAR ) + RIGHT( '0' + CAST( DATEPART(wk, DATE ) AS VARCHAR ), 2 ) AS 'Week Sort'
```